# Getting internal error while evaluating template - xslt

Tags: xslt

I have an issue while converting xml into csv. I'm getting a strange issue and need help.
 This is my XML and XSLT, I'm getting the below error while transforming
"java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error evaluating template  at line 47 in module " that's at the line with content " xsl:template match="UsrOrder"" - bolded text

Tried but unable to figure out the issue.

## XML

Below is the XML input I'm giving to XSLT and this has to be converted to CSV

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <document>
        <businessobjects>
            <UsrOrder>
                <PlanOn>228.01</PlanOn>
                <PROG/>
                <FUND/>
                <ORGN/>
                <ACCT/>
                <Buyer/>
                <Delivery_Notes/>
                <Supplier/>
                <Line>1</Line>
                <Item_Name>NewAir AC-12000CF Airco filter</Item_Name>
                <Unit_of_Measure>STK</Unit_of_Measure>
                <Order_Date/>
                <Retrofit/>
                <Description/>
                <Product_Code/>
                <Related_Invoice_Number/>
                <Order_Attachments/>
                <Quantity>1.0000</Quantity>
                <Unit_Price>9.98</Unit_Price>
            </UsrOrder>
        </businessobjects>
    </document>
    ```    
        XSLT
        ====




<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:csv="csv:csv">
        <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
        <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

        <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','" />

        <csv:columns>
            <column>Supplier</column>
            <column>FUND</column>
            <column>ORGN</column>
            <column>ACCT</column>
            <column>PROG</column>
            <column>PlanOn</column>
            <column>Delivery_Notes</column>
            <column>Buyer</column>
            <column>Line</column>
            <column>ItemName</column>
            <column>Quantity</column>
            <column>Unit_Price</column>
            <column>Unit_of_Measure</column>
            <column>Description</column>
            <column>Product_Code</column>
            <column>Category</column>
            <column>Retrofit</column>
            <column>Related_Invoice_Number</column>
            <column>OrderDate</column>
            <column>OrderAttachments</column>
        </csv:columns>

    <xsl:template match="/document/businessobjects">
            <!-- Output the CSV header -->
            <xsl:for-each select="document('')/*/csv:columns/*">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

            <!-- Output rows for each matched property -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="UsrOrder" />
        </xsl:template>



        **<xsl:template match="UsrOrder">**
            <xsl:variable name="OrderOrderLines" select="." />

            <!-- Loop through the columns in order -->
            <xsl:for-each select="document('')/*/csv:columns/*">
                <!-- Extract the column name and value -->
                <xsl:variable name="column" select="." />
                <xsl:variable name="value" select="$OrderOrderLines/*[name() = $column]" />
                <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
                <!-- Quote the value if required -->
               <!-- <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains($value, '&quot;')">
                        <xsl:variable name="x" select="replace($value, '&quot;',  '&quot;&quot;')"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', $x, '&quot;')"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="contains($value, $delimiter)">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', $value, '&quot;')"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>-->

                <!-- Add the delimiter unless we are the last expression -->
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>

            <!-- Add a newline at the end of the record -->
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
````

Comment: What tool are you using to run the transformation?

Answer (score 0):

"Internal error" means it's a problem in the XSLT processor, not in your code. You can consider things like checking known bugs and upgrading to the latest maintenance release; when you've done that, report it to the vendor.

Another technique is to try a different XSLT processor and see if it comes up with anything. When I run this on the current Saxon version (9.9.1.5), I get:

```
Static error at xsl:template on line 31 column 53 of test.xsl:
  XTSE0120: No character data is allowed between top-level elements
Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation
```

So it could be that if you fix the problem in your stylesheet, the failure will go away. (The characters in question are not actually on line 31, they are the asterisks on line 46.)

Comment: I believe the asterisks are OP's attempt to call attention to the relevant line for the benefit of readers here.